# XAMPP with MySQL instead of MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, drupal, xampp, mariadb

Basically I want to know where I can find a distribution of XAMPP that uses good ol' MySQL instead of MariaDB. I have a Drupal site that runs fine on MySQL 5.5.16, but when I run it on MySQL 10.1.0-MariaDB (which was what the newer XAMPP I downloaded came with), I can't clear the caches without it corrupting the database. I know MariaDB is supposedly the same as MySQL, but this error is happening with one and not the other, and nothing else is different. Where can I get that distribution?

Comment: What cached do you need to clear?

Comment: Usually running drush cc all manages to bork things up. Also running update.php will do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am presuming you are using Windows.

According to WikiPedia, MySQL 5.5.16 came installed with XAMPP 1.7.7 and the last version of XAMPP to come with MySQL (5.6.26) was XAMPP 5.6.12. ([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP#Major_Component_Versions_in_XAMPP_Releases))

You can find all the older versions of XAMPP on [Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/).

Comment: Thanks! I should have researched this a little better; XAMPP's own site didn't provide links to all the versions.